# How to add lines before each and every </head> in multiple HTML Page site?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I hope all are doing well.

How to add `respo_style.css` before closing `</head>` in multiple(in my case there is 65 pages) html + PHP page.

is there any best way to add dynamically

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="respo_style.css" />
```

using code?

In my case i have one `config.php` which is called in every page.

NOTE: Without add or change any other files. Is this possible to add the lines dynamically using jQuery or JavaScript.

Simple things is just add extra additional file in existing without opening each and every files.

Comment: By adding that line into each 65 pages, or creating a template for your `<head>` tags and naming it `head.php` then including that.

Comment: I don't want to add lines in each and every pages i am looking for code which do this.

Comment: PHP has an `include` function. You don't have to copy/paste your master layout in all the views. This is craziness. Include the partial view.

Comment: JS approach: `var link = document.createElement('link'); link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet'); link.setAttribute('href', 'respo_style.css'); document.head.appendChild(link);`

Comment: @Vohuman  : I don't want to open file and add this code. I am trying to do something like add the css file without open all files. Automatically not manually.

Comment: The easiest way would be to use a text editor that allows for search and replace in (all files found in) a folder. Search for `</head>`, replace with `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="respo_style.css" />\n<head>` Notepad++ will do it, it will take less time to do than this comment has taken to write.

Comment: @enhzflep How can i do this on remote network? I am using FTP. and my backup size is almost 1.5Gb

Comment: @enhzflep it will work on small project. Answer is acceptable. (Y)

Comment: No idea mate, you should edit your question to include the fact that it's a bunch of files stored on a remote network, accessible via FTP. The other, natural answer is to write a tiny php script that be run on the server and will open all of the files and make the changes for you. Writing such a script should be a 5 - 10 minute job. There's no need to send the whole file somewhere, make a change and then send the whole file back. Just use the local filesystem on the machine that stores it, using a php script would be my advice. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are a lot of ways but here's an explanation for the fastest/easiest implementation IMO.

For code that is repetitive, you should store that code in one file and call it using PHP's `include_once` function. However in order to use PHP in your files, you would need to use use .php extension instead of .HTML (assuming you files are .HTML) for your webpages.

Here's an example:

```
<head>
<?php include_once("repetitive_code_here.php"); ?> 
</head>
```

Comment: `include` `require` , `require_once`  is not proper answer

Answer (score 0):

If you run `ob_start();` at the beginning of your script, then you can call `ob_get_contents()` to get the page and replace `</head>` with your stylesheet.

```
$string = ob_get_contents();
$link = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="respo_style.css" />';
echo str_replace('</head>', $link . '</head>', $string);
ob_end_clean();
```

or instead of ob_get_contents pass the funtion to `ob_start();`

```
function callback($buffer) {
    $link = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="respo_style.css" />';
    return str_replace('</head>', $link . '</head>', $buffer);
}
ob_start('callback');
```

but you will need to call `ob_end_flush();` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This will work. I have `style.css` in all file. so i can include the `respo_style.css` in `style.css` using this code `@import url("base.css");`

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

page.php (write this in all 65 pages)

```
<?php
require_once('includes/head.php'); //Assuming you put head.php in a folder called "includes" inside the root
?>
//Then the content of the page
```

And head.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="respo_style.css" />
    </head>
```

Comment: This is similar to add  `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="respo_style.css" />` this line in every page.

Comment: Without changing any file i think it is impossible, and then, if he want to add other line in the future he can edit only the head.php file. It is the right way to do that..or maybe call this in the config.db if it is already called in every page